# How to get params from first page of a taxonomy

Tags: hugo

I want to add an opengraph image for a taxonomy list using the image from the first post in the list (.Paginator.Pages). Currently, my ogimage partial looks like this:

```
{{ if .Params.cover_image }}
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Params.cover_image }}">
{{ end }}
{{ if and (.IsNode) (.Site.Params.images) }}
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ index .Site.Params.images 0 }}">
{{ end }}

{{ if and (.IsPage) (not .Params.images) (.Site.Params.images) }}
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ index .Site.Params.images 0 }}">
{{ end }}
```

I know the taxonomy page is the second test (.IsNode) but instead of .Site.Params.images[0] I want .Paginator.Pages[0].Params.cover_image. I just can't quite figure out the right syntax. I assume it's possible but can't figure it out.

Comment: This is in reference to a page where _default/taxonomy.html is selected. The ogimage.html partial is inserted in baseof.html for all pages. I'm trying to customize what it displays for taxonomy pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. While the taxonomy page uses Pagenator, it's the Pages object I need to look at in the baseof template. I also sort of just have to assume every page in a list has an image (which they do). So, the updated ogimage code looks like this:

```
{{ if .Params.cover_image }}
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Params.cover_image }}">
{{ else }}
  {{ if (.IsNode) }}
    {{ range last 1 .Pages }}
      <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Params.cover_image }}">
    {{ end }}
  {{ else }}

  {{ if and (.IsPage) (not .Params.images) (.Site.Params.images) }}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ index .Site.Params.images 0 }}">
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```